# Not able to find text file with JAR in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm very new to Hadoop and I'm having difficulty running what I assume to be a relatively simple program.

I'm trying to set up a JAR to, initially, receive a text file and send it to a new one with all the information inside. Afterwards, once that second text file is created, the JAR will then append text files of the same name of the first to the second.

The code within the JAR file is here:

```
package readWrite;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URI;

public class WriteToHadoop {
    public void writeToHadoop(String uri) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.setBoolean("dfs.support.append", true);
        String file = uri+"/test/houseInfo.txt";
        String fileOut = uri+"/test/mytest.txt";
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(file), conf);
        FileSystem fsout = FileSystem.get(URI.create(fileOut), conf);
        Path filePath = new Path(file);
        Path filePathOut = new Path(fileOut);
        InputStream in = fs.open(filePath);

        if (fsout.exists(filePathOut)){
            FSDataOutputStream fs_append = fsout.append(filePathOut);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fs_append);
            writer.append(fileOut);
            writer.flush();
            fs_append.hflush();
            writer.close();
            fs_append.close();

        } else {
            FSDataOutputStream out = fsout.create(filePathOut, () -> System.out.println("/"));

            IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, true);
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the main:

```java
package readWrite;

public class ExecuteReadWrite {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new WriteToHadoop().writeToHadoop(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } try {
            new ReadFromHadoop().readFromFile(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I created the directory /test/ in the hdfs and placed the houseInfo.txt file in there. Theoretically, when I run

`hadoop jar houseSort.jar <URI>`,

it should find the file and run the code, but it continues to throw FileNotFoundExceptions.

Why is the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a silly fool and didn't write the path down correctly.

```java
String file = uri+"/test/houseInfo.txt";
```

should instead have been:

```java
String file = uri+"/user/hadoopuser/test/houseInfo.txt":
```